# use couchbase mobile in browser ionic hybrid app

Tags: couchbase

I have been investigating using couchbase / couchbase mobile in an iocic hybrid app.  One really great thing about developing with ionic is the fast turn around time by doing most of your development in a browser before deploying to a device.  My question is it possible to use couchbase mobile from a ionic app running in a browser ? I assume that I would have to run an local instance of couchbase mobile on my dev machine and access it by the rest api in my application to test in a browser, then when I go to a device use the couchbase mobile cordova plugins

I found this link which looks like an option
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-local

Other options are to use pouchdb/couchdb combination instead of couchbase.

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB mostly works with Couchbase Sync Gateway (work in progress). It has support for just about everything except attachments.

If you run into any issues, you can replicate from PouchDB to CouchDB, then from that CouchDB to Couchbase Sync Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for that, I do need attachments and per user data so I might go the pouchdb/couchdb combo with individual couchdb databases for each user to get going as there technical stack will be simplified a bit.  It sounds like I can always swap out couchdb for couchbase/couchbase sync gateway at a a later date when attachmemnts are supported in pouchdb.

Comment: Attachments are supported in PouchDB; it's just that CouchDB supports two systems for syncing them: base64 and multipart/mixed. PouchDB implemented only base64, and Couchbase Sync Gateway only implemented multipart/mixed. But luckily CouchDB is our lingua franca, so as I said you can always use it as a middleman. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create / replicate an Pouch DB with pouch it effectively creates a DB in the browser. Take a look here http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser to see which DB it creates.

I've been using this successfully with Ionic for a while now.